# Merging sets into a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

My input is a list of sets of integers. Meaning, each set has an index I need to keep track of. Those (unique) sets contain integers and different sets can have one or more of those integer elements in common (it is also possible that two sets are identical).

My goal is to express those sets not as a list, but rather as a tree-like structure, so I can eliminate the integer elements that are shared by multiple sets. The structure is a directed graph with an artifical root node. The other nodes are the integers found in the sets. The root node will have up to n children (n is the number of sets). Those children are actually a first integer from the different sets and have to be added by the algorithm. There are a few conditions:

- It must be possible to recreate such a set by following one path through the tree.
- A path through the tree must be unambigious, no vertex can have more than one child.
- There is one exception: The artificial root node is allowed to have multiple children (those children would be the starting points for the paths to recreate the sets)

Obviously, it won't be possible to eliminate all duplicates, but I'd like to find an algorithm that finds the most possible eliminations. This is were I have to ask for help. I can do it by hand, but not express it in a formal algorithm that would work in all cases).

Edit: Hopefully this little example illustrates the problem better:

We have three lists, `list0 = [0,3,4,7,8], list1 = [1,2,3,6,7], list3 = [5,6,7,8]`. The index of those lists is the caption of the first edge from the root node `R`. Following this first edge leads to an unambigious path to a node which has no children (in this example its the same node for all three lists, but this needn't be the case). All captions of the nodes on this path form the list with the respective index.

As you can see, the value 7 appears three times, the values 3, 6 and 8 each twice. So the best case scenario would be to get rid of the 5 unneccessary nodes. But with our condition, that no node can have more than one children, it is not always possible to get rid of all duplicates. The graph below shows one possible solution, where the duplicated 6 and 8 could not be resolved.
*[side note: either 6 or 8 could be exchanged with 3, and still have a 12-node solution.]*

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on the structure you want.  You say that you can do it by hand; can you show an example or two and the resulting trees?  I'm not at all clear what *result* you want at the "???", so I can't help you get there.

Comment: I added an example and removed the part with ???, it's hard to describe my algorithmic thinking so I will add it back when I formalized it so its better understandable.

Comment: Much better; thanks.

Comment: Is there a requirement of having only one final node?  This would require a guarantee that the input would have at least one element common to all lists.

Comment: What is the metric for goodness of a solution?  Fewer total nodes?

Comment: Can a value appear more than once in a list?  For instance, is [7, 3, 6, 8, 7] a valid input?

Comment: It is possible to have multiple final nodes, like it would be in the case if the input lists are totally different. Each input is actually a set, so all values are distinct. The goodness would be number of total nodes, yes. Although I'd prefer a solution that finds one good solution directly and I don't have to compare multiple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

*I* don't know of an existing algorithm to solve this, but I think I see some attacks.  First of all, turn your graph upside-down and make it a simple tree, with **7** as the root.  Next, note that your "lists" are unordered: they will work better as sets (assuming no duplication of values).

*Side note: you **can** convert this trivially to a single-root problem -- just add a new, unique symbol to every set.  This will automatically become the root node.*

Now you can attack this with something more like a decision tree.  A recursive algorithm for a sub-tree will yield available solutions.  Your preference of which decomposition to try first should be driven by heuristics, such as

- the value that appears most frequently in the sub-tree's sets
- the largest common subset of all sets.
- the subset that will remove the most elements from the problem.  For instance, a 3-member subset of 3 sets would be better than a 4-member subset of only 2 sets.

This last item is not something you solve in CS 101, and it's not a guaranteed optimal solution on the first strike.  In the past 24 hours, I have mostly convinced myself that there is no straightforward, single attack to get you an optimal solution for all inputs.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The idea with a new symbol is pretty neat. I think I didn't mentioned that I would prefer a straightforward solution like pick the next element, insert it in some specific way and never look back. Not the try-out-multiple-combinations-and-take-the-best approach you gave. It is certainly an improvement and I will play around with this algorithm, but I am not going to accept this answer yet, as long as I have hope that there is a better solution.

Comment: Sounds good.  I played with this a bit over the weekend, and managed to construct a counter-example for any straightforward method I could build.